# Integrating over a subset (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $0 < p < 1$ and $f: X \longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ measuarable with $\int_X f d\mu = 1$.

Prove that $\int_A f^p d\mu \leq \mu(A)^{1-p}$.

Someone please help?

Comment: What exactly should $1<p<1$ mean?

Comment: I mean $0 < p < 1$. Sorry I'll edit that. @LeBtz

Answer (score 2):

It's a direct application of Hölder's inequality, using the exponents $1/p $ and $1/(1-1/(1/p))=1-p $. So
$$
\int_A f^p\,d\mu\leq\left (\int_A (f^p)^{1/p}\,d\mu\right)^p\left (\int_A1^{1/(1-p)}\,d\mu\right)^{1-p}\leq\mu (A)^{1-p}.
$$

Comment: Why is the exponent $\frac{1}{p}$ and $1/(1-1/(1/p))$. Sorry I am confuse, but thank you very much for helping me with this.

Comment: The $1/p$ is to cancel the $p$ so one can use that $\int f=1$. In Hölder, once you choose an exponent $r$, the other has to be $q$ such that $\frac1r+\frac1q=1$, so $$q=\frac1{1-\frac1r}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just an application of Holder's inequality. Try using it to bound
$$\int_Af^pd\mu = \int_{X} f^p \cdot \mathbb{1}_{A} d \mu.$$

Edit: extra clarification.

Holder's inequality states

$\|hg\|_1 \le \|h\|_r\|g\|_s =\left(\int_X |h|^r d\mu\right)^{1/r} \cdot \left(\int_X |g|^s d\mu\right)^{1/s}$

if $r,s \in [1,\infty]$ satisfy $1/r + 1/s =1$.

We are taking $h = f^p$, $g=1_A$ and $r=1/p$ (notice that $r \in [1,\infty]$ since $0<p<1$). To use Holder's we need $1/s = 1 - 1/r = 1-p $ i.e. $s = 1/(1-p)$.

Combining all of this (and noticing that $f$ is positive so we need not worry about absolute values),

\begin{align*}
\int_A f^p d\mu &= \int_X f^p \cdot 1_A d\mu\\
&\le \left(\int_X(f^p)^{1/p}d\mu\right)^p \cdot\left(\int_X (1_A)^{1/(1-p)} d\mu\right)^{1-p}\\
&= 1 \cdot \left(\int_X 1_A d\mu\right)^{1-p}\\
&= \mu(A)^{1-p}
\end{align*}

Comment: $\int_A f^p d\mu \leq (\int_X f^p d\mu)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ x $\int_X 1_A d\mu$ Like this?

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed out the '$p$' powers of $f$. I'll add those in. You're nearly there, you just need to make sure you're using Holder's inequality correctly.

Comment: $\int_A f^p d\mu \leq (\int_X f^p d\mu)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ x $(\int_X 1_A d\mu)^{1-p}$ $\leq \mu(A)^{1-p}$? Can you please tell me where did I go wrong? Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the last inequality? You don't have any information about $\int_X f^p d \mu$.

Comment: I'll add an edit to explain how to use the inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that I can just cancel out the p by raising it with 1/p and so I can get the $\int_X f d\mu = 1$

Comment: Right idea, but in your post, the $1/p$ was 'outside the integral' so it didn't cancel - may have just been a typo :) Glad that helps

Comment: Yep! So much thanks!